# Backing store when mapping/unmapping an X11 window?

Tags: x11

My X11 client/server are set up to use a backing store (backing_store = WhenMapped), which works fine when my window is partially obscured: remove what's obscuring the window and the now-visible part is refreshed from the backing store with no need for me to repaint...

...but it's not working when the window is unmapped then mapped again: I get UnmapNotify then MapNotify events, but my window is blank when mapped and I have to repaint the whole thing myself.

So my question: How do I get the backing store to work for Unmap/Map as well as Expose?  (backing_store = Always) made no difference.

System: Ubuntu 16.04, X.Org X Server 1.19.3

Thank you

Comment: A hack to avoid handling expose events is to create a pixmap of the size of the window and set it as the background pixmap. The server will then refresh from this pixmap. The server is free to make a copy of the pixmap so It is undefined if any changes you make to the pixmap are seen, without doing another call to `XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap()`.

Comment: Do you not need to handle all expose events, just in case the server throws away the backing store.

Answer (score 2):

By `backing_store = always` I presume you mean the window attributes in your client code?  But are you sure `BackingStore` option is enabled for your X server?  Presuming Xorg, you should locate your log (`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, or more recently `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`) and grep for `Backing store`:

```
> grep 'Backing store' ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log

[    67.851] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
```

If it's not enabled, you could try creating `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-backing-store.conf` (or adding it to an existing file, if you have one with a `Device` section):

```
Section "Device"
  Option "BackingStore" "on"
EndSection
```

Restart X and see if the option is enabled in the Xorg.0.log.

There is also the `+bs` option (note the +) to Xorg itself, which I have used successfully in the past.

```
> Xorg --help
...
+bs      enable any backing store support
```

Comment: Hi...  The backing store is definitely enabled on the server-- I made sure, which is how I got this far (working for Expose, but not for Map).  The log does also verify this: "FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled".  So it's working, but not when I unmap then re-map the window.

Comment: @ian.macky: fair enough, but there is also the window attribute "save-under", which works for Expose but not for Map, so it seemed possible that you were not really testing backing store even for Expose.  May I ask what window manager you're using, and whether you've tried this with a different one?

Comment: The comment below [this answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17035752) sounds like it's worth trying, in your `MapNotify` handler.  You use `XClearArea()` of one pixel, and it will trigger an `Expose` event.  Alternatively, you can try creating a synthetic `Expose` event and send it using `XSendEvent()`.  Also it should be mentioned, backing store is only a hint to the server, and might not be honored.

Comment: Setting save-under/CWSaveUnder doesn't make any difference (just tried it).  Note with the backing store enabled, I **don't** get Expose events when an obscured part of the window is uncovered-- it's just repainted from the backing store and I don't have to deal with it, as expected.  With no backing store, I **do** get Expose events under same conditions.   When a window is Unmapped then Mapped, **should** it start out with the saved contents from the backing store??  Am I barking up the wrong tree?  I'm using an ancient window manager but don't see how would WM choice would affect anything.

Comment: I just checked with an X client of my own, and I **do** get an expose event when I XUnmapWindow() and then XMapWindow().  (And the bitmap image is restored without redrawing.)  So you might like to try the tricks in my previous comment, to force an Expose event on Map?  I'm interested in your problem and would like to help, but it's been some time since I messed with this stuff.  My app overrides the WM so it might be a bad comparison.